# XML schema on choice element

Tags: xml, schema

i wanted to constraint the Grade element to show only 3 possibilities that is GradeA or GradeB or GradeA and Grade B but my logic is wrong. As for my code it make sures that either GradeA or GradeB will be shown.But it also makes that GradeB or GradeA can appear 2 times,and i dont want them to appear 2 time.The result can only appear either GradeA,GradeB or GradeA and GradeB.can anyone show me on the correct way to code this.

```
<Grade>
  <GradeA/>
  <GradeB/>
</Grade>
```

Below is the code that i have.

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
   <xsd:element name="GradeA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="GradeB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both elements are present, can they appear in either order?

You want something like:

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="GradeA">
     <xs:element ref="GradeB" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="GradeB">
     <xs:element ref="GradeA" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```